# '[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...'

Tags: javascript, server, nodemon

I was hoping to get some help, I am running `npm start` and I am getting an error for the `server.js` file.

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...

[nodemon] starting `node server.js`

/Users/johnngo/Desktop/LambdaSchool/HTTP-AJAX/server.js:59
  const friend = { id: getNewId(), ...req.body };

   ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...

    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:425:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:146:9)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

[image]

Please advise

Comment: What's your Node version? Check by running `node -v` into the terminal. I believe the version you're running doesn't support [Rest Parameters](https://node.green/#ES2015-syntax-rest-parameters)

Comment: node version is v8.1.2, it looks like node may have problems supporting spread operator {...}, not sure how to fix this

Comment: `{ id: getNewId(), ...req.body }` what kind of object structure is this? Don't even look like destructuring.

Comment: tbh, I couldn't tell you, the repository is from lambda school - https://github.com/LambdaSchool/HTTP-AJAX, it's in the server.js file, it seems like it's only me that's having an issue.

Comment: I tried to uninstall node and I now get this message.
johnngo (master *) Sprint-Challenge--Redux $ npm start
bash: /Users/johnngo/.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.2/bin/npm: No such file or directory
johnngo (master *) Sprint-Challenge--Redux $ npm install
bash: /Users/johnngo/.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.2/bin/npm: No such file or directory

Comment: I installed node v10.0 and it seems to work, however, it continues to go back to the old version v7.2.2, how can I make this permanent, I go to echo $PATH and I get this.

/Users/johnngo/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/johnngo/.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.2/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/johnngo/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:yarn global bin:yarn global bin

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer is

to change the **IpWhitelist** go to edit and

refresh it and again connect it....